# Displaying ©, & symbol in excel with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet

I am exporting my data into an excel file with Spreadsheet gem and Ruby on Rails. I want to add header and footer to my excel file. The problem is when i am doing this, the copyright symbol, ampersand symbol and registered symbol are not displaying. Either it throws multibyte character error or it simply displays nothing.

I have gone through all similar problems and tried even **# encoding utf-8** and "**# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-**". It is of no use. 
When i tried to use escape sequence("\u00A9" - unicode code for © ), the file format is being corrupted. Any possible solutions for this problem? Am i missing something?
Kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
def do_test
  book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
  sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
  sheet1[0,0] = "\u00a9"
  book.write "./sample.xls"
end
```

It is possible that you may have set the spreadsheet encoding to something other than UTF-8 at some point.  You can check `Spreadsheet.client_encoding` to see what is being used.

**UPDATE**

The `add_header/footer` code is very encoding specific.  Here is the code used:

```
def write_header
  write_op opcode(:header), [@worksheet.header.bytesize, 0].pack("vC"), @worksheet.header
end
```

The Excel writer is using Unicode-1200 (UTF-16 little endian) by default.  This may mean that you need to encode any non-standard characters using `"\u00a9".encode('UTF-16LE')` in order to get this to work...

Comment: Ya its working in the excel sheet's content @PinnyM. But i want the symbol to add to the Header of excel while i am printing. While doing so, it says file is corrupted. Also i checked client_encoding which UTF-8 only.

Comment: 'Header' as in the top row, or the sheet name, or something else? Perhaps posting some code showing what you are attempting to do would help...

Comment: This is the code i wrote in my controller.rb.    sheet.add_header( "Company Name")    sheet.add_footer( "Company Name ©") If i am giving like this, file format error rises when i try to open the file after writing that file. So i tried to add the symbol as follows.    sheet.add_footer("Company Name \u00a9"). By doing so i m getting invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) error.

Comment: What version of spreadsheet gem are you running?  I'm getting `undefined method 'add_header'` when I try this on the latest 0.7.3

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending your valuable time for me. I am using spreadsheet-0.6.5.7. 
There is no method like add_header or add_footer in this version of gem. Hence i referred the following link to customize Header of my worksheet.
I used that code in my config/initializer. 
If you look at this link, you would understand. 
[link](http://pullmonkey.com/2012/04/26/headers-and-footers-in-rubys-spreadsheet-gem/)